Assistance Required: Error Code "AccessToBotDenied" When Logging into Copilot Studio Bot
I am seeking assistance with an issue I encountered while trying to log into the Copilot Studio bot authenticated using AAD authentication. Upon attempting to access the bot, I received the following error message:  "Sorry, something unexpected happened. We’re looking into it. Error code: AccessToBotDenied."

Could someone please assist me in resolving this issue? Any guidance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.


You need to Deletegate the openid and profile under OpenId permissions, Refer the MS Doc  Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-copilot-studio/configuration-authentication-azure-ad#configure-manual-authentication for more derails

It’s already added in API permissions, and I have admin consent as well. Are there any additional requirements to resolve this issue?

Please follow the MS Doc to resolve the issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-copilot-studio/configuration-authentication-azure-ad#configure-manual-authentication

I hope this helps resolve your issue.

No , the issue still persists although following all of the steps

Are you still getting same issue?

Yes I am . The issue is not yet resolved . Only solution I have found that user needs to be added to environment with Environment maker role . But that's not possinle in RL scenarios . So is there any alternate approach ?

You need to share the Copilot to everyone in the organization (by choosing the readio option "User - can use this copilot") through the share button available next to settings. And later the app can be restricted through the M365 admin center


